# MySQL: cannot add constant field at start of SELECT. Error 1064

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, mysql-error-1064

Using MariaDB v. 10, I try to add a custom constant as the first column of my `SELECT` query, before all other columns `*`. This results in the generic syntax error 1064.

For example:

```
# mysql -u root -p$mypass -D mysql -e "SELECT 'X', * FROM user;"
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '* FROM user' at line 1
```

If I select only some columns, it works:

```
# mysql -u root -p$mypass -D mysql -e "SELECT 'X', host, user FROM user;"
+---+-----------------+------------------+
| X | host            | user             |
+---+-----------------+------------------+
| X | 127.0.0.1       | root             |
| X | ::1             | root             |
...
```

And it also works if I use `*` to select all columns, *but put my constant column after it*:

```
# mysql -u root -p$mypass -D mysql -e "SELECT *, 'X' FROM user;"  
... [long, correct output] ...
```

How can I do a `SELECT 'some constant', * FROM my_table` to avoid this strange error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only use `SELECT *` if it's the first thing in the `SELECT` list. If it's mixed in with other values, you need to use a table name or alias, so do

```
SELECT 'X', user.* FROM user;
```

Comment: Well, that was fast! And even 2 answers. Thanks to both of you. It works.

Answer (score 2):

Use a table alias for `*`.  I would also give the first column as name:

```
SELECT 'X' as col, u.*
FROM user u;
```

MySQL requires a qualification for `*` when it is selected with other values.